# Hotcorner for minimize current window

Tags: release-juno, hot-corners, minimize

This used to be an option in

```
System Settings > Desktop > Hot Corners
```

I don't see it in Juno.
Why was this removed? I love, love, love this feature and it is the first thing I activate on a new install.
How can I get it back?
Thanks! Loving Juno so far.

Comment: For the record `Hot corners` are still there in Juno. Not sure why this user is not seeing it.

Answer (score 3):

In Terminal, without installing anything:
`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-topright 'minimize-current'`

Comment: > gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-topright 'minimize-current'
> and what is the command for the low right corner? i've tried to change it to "lowright" but it didn't work. please help anyone :)

Comment: I would imagine it is bottomright

Answer (score 1):

To add a minimize current window hot corner in Juno:

Install dconf editor

Run dconf editor and navigate to 
org > pantheon > desktop > gala > behavior
Select the corner you want and click on it
Click on custom behavior and select 'minimize-current'
You're all set!

Answer (score 0):

Install `xdotool` using apt.

In the Settings -> Desktop -> Hot corners, pick the hot corner you want. Choose `Execute custom command`. Put this in as the custom command:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
```